# Como pegar o endereço,longitude e latitude pelo Cep usando o Google Maps Api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou fazendo um projeto onde preciso que o usuário informe o Cep e que automaticamente preencha os campos de um formulário tais campos sendo: Rua,Bairro,Cidade,estou procurando a alguns dias.Por favor quem souber como posso fazer esta aplicação agradeço.

Comment: Você já tentou usar openlayers?

Comment: Verifique se este link não o ajuda , ok? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding